# How to filter match in top 3 - elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am having the following data in the elasticsearch

```
{
    "_index": "media",
    "_type": "information",
    "_id": "6838",
    "_source": {
        "demographics_countries": {
            "AE": 0.17543859649122806,
            "CA": 0.013157894736842105,
            "FR": 0.017543859649122806,
            "GB": 0.043859649122807015,
            "IT": 0.02631578947368421,
            "LB": 0.013157894736842105,
            "SA": 0.49122807017543857,
            "TR": 0.017543859649122806,
            "US": 0.09210526315789472
        }
    }
},
{
    "_index": "media",
    "_type": "information",
    "_id": "57696",
    "_source": {
        "demographics_countries": {
            "TN": 0.8125,
            "MA": 0.034375,
            "DZ": 0.032812,
            "FR": 0.0125,
            "EG": 0.0125,
            "IN": 0.009375,
            "SA": 0.009375
    }
}
]
```

***Expected result:***

Find out an document having specific country `SA` (saudi arabia) is among top 3 in `demographics_countries`

**For example:**

"_id": "6838" (first document) is matched because `SA` (saudi arabia) is among top 3 in the  `demographics_countries` in the above mentioned example document.

Tried ? : I have tried to filter using top_hits, But it's not working as expected.

Any suggestion will be grateful

Comment: It's quite unclear what are you trying to achieve here. What's your logic and what are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas Thanks. Having social media document with demographics country listing, We have to find out specific country is among the top 3 in each document. For example Specific country is given as "SA" which is short code for  saudi arabia. Please let me know if anything needs to elaborated

Answer (score 0):

With the current data model it's quite difficult to do that. What I'd suggest might be not the easiest way to do it, but it will definitely be the fastest to query eventually.

I'd suggest remodelling your documents to already include top countries:

```json
[
  {
    "_index": "media",
    "_type": "information",
    "_id": "6838",
    "_source": {
      "top_demographics_countries": ["TN", "MA", "DZ"],
      "demographics_countries": {
        "AE": 0.17543859649122806,
        "CA": 0.013157894736842105,
        "FR": 0.017543859649122806,
        "GB": 0.043859649122807015,
        "IT": 0.02631578947368421,
        "LB": 0.013157894736842105,
        "SA": 0.49122807017543857,
        "TR": 0.017543859649122806,
        "US": 0.09210526315789472
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "media",
    "_type": "information",
    "_id": "57696",
    "_source": {
      "top_demographics_countries": ["TN", "MA", "DZ"],
      "demographics_countries": {
        "TN": 0.8125,
        "MA": 0.034375,
        "DZ": 0.032812,
        "FR": 0.0125,
        "EG": 0.0125,
        "IN": 0.009375,
        "SA": 0.009375
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Ignore values I've picked for `top_demographics_countries`. With this kind of approach, you can always precalculate top and then you could use a simple terms query to check if document contains that value or not:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "top_demographics_countries": "SA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's going to be cheaper to compute them once during saving compared to always building that clause dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

@Evaldas is right -- it's better to extract the top 3 beforehand.

But if you can't help yourself and feel compelled to use java/painless, here's one approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "demographics_countries.SA"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                def tuple_list = new ArrayList();                
                
                for (def c : params.all_countries) {
                  def key = 'demographics_countries.'+c;
                  if (!doc.containsKey(key) || doc[key].size() == 0) {
                    continue;
                  }
                  def val = doc[key].value;
                  tuple_list.add([c, val]);
                }
                
                // sort tuple list by the country values
                Collections.sort(tuple_list, (arr1, arr2) -> arr1[1] < arr2[1] ? 1 : -1);
                
                // slice & take only the top 3        
                def top_3_countries = tuple_list.subList(0, 3).stream().map(arr -> arr[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
                
                return top_3_countries.size() >=3 && top_3_countries.contains(params.country_of_interest);
              """,
              "params": {
                "country_of_interest": "SA",
                "all_countries": [
                  "AE",
                  "CA",
                  "FR",
                  "GB",
                  "IT",
                  "LB",
                  "SA",
                  "TR",
                  "US",
                  "TN",
                  "MA",
                  "DZ",
                  "EG",
                  "IN"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```